# Using book.cls makes pdf even pages to be aligned to the right and odd pages to the left

Tags: pdf, thesis, alignment

I have started to use `book.cls` instead of `llncs.cls`.
I have copied the content of `book.cls` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teymourlouie/ui-thesis-template/master/book.cls).

For some reason, the pdf output has the even pages aligned to the right while the odd pages are (correctly) aligned to the left.

See the following zoomed-out pdf for example:
[image]

in this example the first page on the image is an even page so it is aligned to the right.
I would like all pages to be aligned as in the second page (which has odd number).

I have the following before `\begin{documnet}`:

```
\let\oldvec\vec

\documentclass[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,commentsnumbered]{book}

\let\vec\oldvec

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\large\bfseries}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{8pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-3em}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\large\bfseries}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt} 

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newcommand {\ignore} [1] {} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
```

What could be the reason and how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: In the `book` class outer margins are wider than inner margins. That's perfectly normal (and a FAQ).

Comment: If you don't like the fact that `book.cls` is using a two-sided layout, you can disable this by using the `oneside` class option.

Comment: you don't need to copy book.cls from anywhere, it is a core latex file you should use the book.cls that comes with your latex system

Comment: open up most books and you will see this layout with the position of the text block on the right hand page being a mirror of the position on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @egreg mentioned in his comment, this is the normal and expected behaviour for a book, as you want the outer margins to be roughly as wide as the two inner margins in sum. This gives a balanced look in duplex print and matches what is considered as good typography.

If you want to disable this behaviour it suffices to provide `oneside` as a class option:

```latex
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{duckuments} % just for dummy content, otherwise not needed

\begin{document}
\duckument % dummy content
\end{document}
```

[image]